# Adding google.maps.latlng within a loop

Tags: java, javascript, jsf-2

I am new to Java Script. I am using it, in combination with Java Server Faces 2.0. 
I want to add some points to define a Polilyne using GoogleMaps Apiv3. My problem is that I can't add a FOR statement to the javascript, because it dumps. If I comment this FOR loop, it also dumps. The dump I am getting is: "javax.servlet.ServletException: null source".
Has anyone any suggestion to solve this? Thanks in advance, Emanuel

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() 
{ 
  var longit = "${dateRange.longitude}" ;
  var lat = "${dateRange.latitude}" ;
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, longit);
  var myOptions = 
  {
    zoom: 15,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  var points = []; 
  var cadena1 = "${dateRange.latArray}" ;
  var cadena2 = "${dateRange.longArray}" ;
  var latArray = cadena1.split('?');
  var longArray = cadena2.split('?');

  /* The code Below is the one that fails */
  for (var i=0; i < latArray.length; i++)
  { 
    points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(latArray[i], longArray[i]));         
  }
  /* Finish of the error code */

  // The Polilyne is created
  var mapPath = new google.maps.Polyline
  ({
    path: points,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 4
  });
  mapPath.setMap(map);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <h:graphicImage url="http://localhost:8080/gps_tracking/faces/resources/images/logo.jpg">    
  </h:graphicImage>
  <h1 align="center">Sol-Tech</h1><br  />
  <hr></hr>
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: What error message do you get when you leave the for loop in?

Comment: Also, have you verified that latArray and longArray have the same number of items in them?

Comment: E.Z. Hart, I have added to the post, the error I am getting in Eclipse. Please tell me if you need something else.

Comment: What are the values of dateRange.longitude, dateRange.latitude, dateRange.latArray, and dateRange.longArray? It doesn't look like this is a JavaScript problem, it looks like your problem is in the Java code. Are you maybe trying to retrieve values which don't exist?